# Detect scroll in JS on object with `overflow: hidden`

Tags: javascript, css

How do I detect scroll position with pure JavaScript (please, no jQuery) on element that has
`overflow-x: hidden` 
set in CSS? Is it even possible?

To clarify - it is not possible to attach scroll event listener to object that has any overflow set in it. I would like to detect Y scroll position within that object.

Comment: Surely there will be no scroll as the overflow is hidden so scrollTop will always be 0

Comment: Pete, `overflow-x` is hidden, which enables objects inside to scroll vertically. It is not possible to attach event listener for scroll Y position if wrapper object has any overflow on it. This is the main problem.

Comment: Could you please explain why is it impossible to attach a scroll event listener? This could affect as well whether other solutions are applicable or not.

Comment: Ilya, If you have overflow-x on element where you want to listen for scroll, even if that object is of the same dimensions as window, it will not work. One would think that scrollY position will be detected, but it is not.

Solution is apparently to move `overflow-x` to `body` instead of that element, and then listen for scroll.

Comment: @VladimirJovanović, works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/dmx0byr9/

Comment: Thanks Ilya, I will compare it with my code and will try to figure out where I made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You can use getComputedStyle().

```
var element = document.getElementById('overflowobject'),
    style = window.getComputedStyle(element),
    overflowX = style.getPropertyValue('overflow-x');
```

Then you can check `overflowX == 'hidden'`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle